SharePoint UI get distorted when we migrate to SharePoint 2019 on premise
Please help us in fixing this issue when we add list on page it gets distorted icons.
Please find below image


Do you use a custom master page or a custom style sheet?

yes custom master page with custom css. but this error occur on some pages other pages are ok.

It could be browser compatibility, check if you change the default mode for IE in the HTML code of the master page.

It comes when we add list on page
